# Sharepoint 2010 authentication with php

Tags: php, curl, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, basic-authentication

I am creating an application in which i need to connect the sharepoint 2010 with PHP.I am using thybag sharepoint api to connect the server.I am able to upload the file to already existing folder with curl and php.

While i am getting access denied error when trying to create a folder at the sharepoint library.Below error i am getting:
**Exception: Access Denied in C:\wamp\www\sharepoint\Thybag\Auth\SoapClientAuth.php on line 122**

My Basic authentication is enabled to the sharepoint server but still getting this error for authentication.

Please let me know the solution asap.Is there any other setting which neeed to be enabled.

Comment: you'd need to figure out exactly what you're being denied access to... SP itself? or some function inside SP?

Comment: I think there is some error due to some authentication but not able to figure out other than Basic authentication what needs to be Enable

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the API isn't currently connecting at all, it may be worth checking how your setting up SharePointAPI object as the `SoapClientAuth` class shouldn't be being used if you are connecting using basic auth? (its only used for NTLM)

For basic authentication all you should need is:

`$sp = new SharePointAPI('<username>', '<password>', '<path_to_WSDL>');`

If other parts of the API are working; would you be able to give a bit more detail on what code you are attempting to run to create the folder?